# Pullback of $w_1$ for 3-manifolds

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, 3-manifolds, stiefel-whitney

Given closed $3$-manifolds $M$ and $N$
and an element $\alpha\in H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$,
when does there exist a map $f:M\to N$
such that $\alpha=f^*(w_1(N))$?

Answer (score 4):

This basically boils down to

1. Understanding what the class $w_1$ represents, and
2. Doing obstruction theory.

This is generally not an easy question to answer, since obstruction theory requires you to have a clear understanding of some cell decomposition of the domain $M$, as well as the homotopy groups of the target $N$.  Typically one cannot say much for general manifolds, but here is one example of the type of thing that this theory implies:

---

Suppose $N$ is simply connected, then $H^1(N;\mathbb Z/2)=0$ and thus the only possible $\alpha$ is the zero class, and this can be realized by a constant map $f:M\to\{n_0\}\subseteq N$.

---

Aside from obstruction theory, there aren't any theories that I know of that produce continuous maps.  Also you have written $w_1(N)$, which typically refers to the 1st SW class of the tangent bundle.  This indicates that you are working with smooth manifolds (though it is possible to make sense of $w_1(N)$ in the topological case).  I mention this only to emphasize that obstruction theory is only attempting to build for you a *continuous* map.  If that is fine for you, great!  If not, then you would further need to use smoothing theory to see if any of the resultant maps can be made smooth.

I recommend Milnor and Stasheff's 'Characteristic Classes' for further intuition about $w_1$, and I like the treatment of obstruction theory given in Davis and Kirk's 'Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology'

Comment: Any continuous map between smooth manifolds is homotopic to a smooth map, so it suffices to consider continuous maps for the problem

Comment: And every topological 3-manifold admits a unique smooth structure, so $w_1$ is well-defined.

Comment: moreover, Stiefel-Whitney classes are homotopy invariant, so in fact the problem is reduced to the homotopy cathegory

Comment: on the other hand, the Stiefel-Whitney classes *of a manifold* have some special properties, e.g. $w_1(N)^2=w_2(N)$, which maybe can help

Answer (score 1):

For manifolds $M,N$ of dimension $<3$ I know the complete answer for the similar question.

---

If $M,N$ are closed $1$-manifolds, obviously, $f$ exists if and only if $\alpha=0$.

---

If $M,N$ are closed $2$-manifolds, $f$ exists if and only if any of the following four conditions hold:

- $\alpha=0$;
- $w_1(N)\ne0$ and $\alpha^2=0$;
- $w_2(N)\ne0$, $\alpha=w_1(M)$ and $\chi(M)\le\chi(N)$;
- $w_2(N)\ne0$, $\alpha^2\ne0$ and $\chi(M)<\chi(N)$.

In [the proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.00205) I used the technique of *simple closed curves on surfaces*, inspired by Farb-Margalit.

---

Maybe, there is some similar methods and arguments in case of $3$-manifolds?